# How to increase the number via input value?

Tags: jquery, html

I want that depending on the number of characters entered in input, the number in the span tag should increase. I want that one character equal to 5. It works, but a little bit wrong.

```js
$(function() {
  var target = $('[data-field="target"]');

  $(document).on('input', '[data-field="item"]', function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var price = parseFloat($(".price").text());
    target.html(item.val().length * 5 + price);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" data-field="item">
  <span data-field="target" class="price">60</span>
</form>
```

The result that I want to achieve that on every character that I enter in input it will increase to 5.

For example:

> 60 + one character in input = 65;
>
> 60 + two character in input = 70;

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you update the value you use after each calculation. Therefore your starting figure increases exponentially.

To fix this you need a method of storing, and keeping, the starting figure for each calculation. To achieve that you can use a `data` attribute on the `.price` element, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $target = $('[data-field="target"]');

  $(document).on('input', '[data-field="item"]', function() {
    var price = $(".price").data('starting-price');
    $target.html($(this).val().length * 5 + price);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" data-field="item">
  <span data-field="target" class="price" data-starting-price="60">60</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code. Please see

```js
$(function () {
    var target = $('[data-field="target"]');
    const price = 60;

    $(document).on('input', 'input[data-field="item"]', function () {
        var item = $(this);
        target.html(item.val().length * 5 + price);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" data-field="item">
  <span data-field="target" class="price">60</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that if we put the number directly to the variable it will work. Unfortunately I need to get the number from the span tag. But thanks anyway.